# undefined reference to symbol / ..libdl.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Tags: linux

I currently have a problem compiling with gitian-builder.

It tells me this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I don't find anything useful.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try searching here for `libcrypto DSO` ? I see several Q/As that maybe helpful. Good luck.

Comment: thanks I will check that

Comment: hey, tried to fix it but it still isn't working

Comment: @ChristianBenz have you found a solution?

Comment: @ChristianBenz any news?

Answer (score 4):

Try the following

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE "${CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE} -ldl")
```

Comment: thanks, this solved the issue for our case